Sufficient conditions for a continuous transform to have an (infinitesimal) generator
(Apologies for such a long question: I suspect I lack the specific vocabulary to ask it more succinctly!)
Consider a smooth function $\sigma:\left(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ that maps any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to some other point in the same space, according to some parameter $\varepsilon$; i.e. a given point $\mathbf{q_0}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is mapped to:
$$\mathbf{q_\varepsilon}=\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q_0}\right).$$
Additionally let this function be equivalent to the identity when $\varepsilon=0$:
$$\mathbf{q_0}=\sigma\left(0,\mathbf{q_0}\right).$$
Now if we apply this transform to $\mathbf{q_0}$ for an infinitesimally small value of the parameter ($d\varepsilon$) we have (expanding about zero):
$$\begin{align}\mathbf{q_{d\varepsilon}}&=\sigma\left(0,\mathbf{q_0}\right)+\sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{q_0}\right)d\varepsilon+\mathcal{O}\left(d\varepsilon^2\right)\\ &=\mathbf{q_0}+\sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{q_0}\right)d\varepsilon+\mathcal{O}\left(d\varepsilon^2\right)\end{align}$$
where $\sigma_{,1}$ indicates the partial derivative of $\sigma$ w.r.t. its first argument.
Applying this infinitesimal transform repeatedly to its own image (i.e. using $\sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{q}\right)$ as a generator) we can generate a new transform $\tilde{\sigma}$. At some intermediate value $\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}$ in this repetitive process we have:
$$\mathbf{\tilde{q}_{\varepsilon+d\varepsilon}} = \mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}+\sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}\right)d\varepsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}}{d\varepsilon}=\sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}\right) \qquad \text{[*]}$$
Thus the generated transform $\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}=\tilde{\sigma}\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q_0}\right)$ can be found by solving the set of ODEs [*] with suitable boundary conditions.
Consider these illustrative examples:
1. $\quad \sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right) = e^\varepsilon\mathbf{q}$
Applying this recursively for infinitesimal values of the parameter yields the ODEs:
$$\frac{d\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}}{d\varepsilon} = \sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}\right)=\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}$$
which has the solution $\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}=\mathbf{q_0}e^\varepsilon$ (applying boundary conditions $\mathbf{\tilde{q}_0}=\mathbf{q_0}$).
So we have $\tilde{\sigma}\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)=\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)$.
2. $\quad \sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)=\mathbf{q}+\left(\varepsilon^2
-3\varepsilon\right)\mathbf{k}$
Applying this recursively for infinitesimal values yields the ODEs:
$$\frac{d\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}}{d\varepsilon}=-3\mathbf{k}$$
with solution $\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}=\mathbf{q_0}-3\varepsilon\mathbf{k}$.
Thus while $\tilde{\sigma}\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)\neq\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)$ it is nevertheless the case that for any $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find an $\varepsilon^\prime \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{\sigma}\left(\varepsilon^\prime,\mathbf{q}\right)=\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)$.  Specifically:
$$\tilde{\sigma}\left(\varepsilon-\tfrac{1}{3}\varepsilon^2,\mathbf{q}\right)=\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)$$
so it could be argued that $\tilde{\sigma}$ and $\sigma$ belong to some suitably defined equivalence class.
3. $\quad \sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)=\mathbf{q}+\varepsilon\mathbf{k}+\left(\varepsilon-2\varepsilon^2\right)\mathbf{m}$
Applying this recursively for infinitesimal values yields the ODEs:
$$\frac{d\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}}{d\varepsilon}=\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{m}$$
with solution $\mathbf{\tilde{q}_\varepsilon}=\mathbf{q_0} + \varepsilon\left(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{m}\right)$.
In this case $\tilde{\sigma}$ is not even equivalent to $\sigma$, for instance there exists  no value of $\varepsilon^\prime$ such that:
$$\tilde{\sigma}\left(\varepsilon^\prime,\mathbf{q_0}\right)=\sigma\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\mathbf{q_0}\right)=\mathbf{q_0}+\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{k}.$$
In fact I cannot currently think of any infinitesimal transform that would generate $\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q_0}\right)$ in this case.
Finally: The question
So my questions are:

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a smooth continuous transform $\sigma\left(\varepsilon,\mathbf{q}\right)$ to have an infinitesimal generator? (Possibly allowing instead generators for transforms that are effectively equivalent to $\sigma$.)

What (if any) additional conditions are required for this generator to specifically be $\sigma_{,1}\left(0,\mathbf{q}\right)$?



Where is your question coming from? or what motivated you to ask this question? This looks much like semigroup theory in PDEs, where we have a family of operators ${P_t}_{t\geq 0}$ on a Banach space $X$. Then under suitable conditions there is a unique infinitesimal generator $L$ such that differential of $P_t$ is $L$. A common example is Heat kernal (operator) and Laplacian.

@cct My motivation comes from Noether's theorem / variational symmetries of actions.  Typically one says that only infinitesimal symmetries need be considered in the theorem because any symmetry can always be built up from the repeated application of an infinitesimal one.  But as pointed out above there are actually cts transforms of the coordinate space that aren't reconstructable this way.  So I wondered what conditions are implicitly being imposed on the symmetry transform by assuming it can be so constructed, and what this says about the nature of those that can't be.

@cct PS I've found it's actually possible to rederive Noether's theorem for finite instead of infinitesimal transforms (unless I've made a mistake) and the resulting conserved quantities still only depend on what I have called $\sigma_{,1}(0,q)$ above, which further intrigues me about transforms for which this is not an infinitesimal generator and what their nature might be.

Mathematically, the existence of the operator you are looking for is given for free if you already assume the action to be smooth, since the infinitesimal generator is usually defined as $$ \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\sigma(t,\cdot)-\sigma(0,\cdot)}{t}.$$ We will usually assume the semigroup property: $ \sigma(t,\sigma(s,\cdot)) = \sigma(t+s,\cdot)$ and continuity in the first variable. In context of Lie group, we have $\sigma(t,X)=\exp(tX)$ where $\exp$ is the exponential map; in the context of PDEs/stochastic process, we have $\sigma(t,f)=P_tf$ where ${P_t}_{t\geq 0}$ is a family of operators.

@cct That semigroup property is what I'm after (if I understand right).  Defining the infinitesimal generator as the tangent vector at zero, as per the exponential map, I see it must by defn be the limit you give, equivalent I believe to my $\sigma_{,1}(0,q)$.  But to then recover the original function $\sigma$ by repeated application of this generator seems to require the property you state $\sigma(t,\sigma(s,\cdot))=\sigma(t+s,\cdot)$ also hold true.  Is there a name for funcs that satisfy that property?  I'd love a reference that discusses the property - I've not seen it before.  Thanks!

I may had made a bad assumption that you have the mathematical background while writing the comments. Let me describe some basic ideas of the infinitesimal generator and the semigroup I mentioned in as plain english as I can. Let's fix the notations. Given an action $ \sigma : A \times B \to B $, write variable in $A$ by $t$ and variable in $B$ by $x$.
I will focus on the motivation and intuition of how to think about these properties that we require it to satisfy. This could be biased but it makes sense to me so hopefully after reading this, these properties look less random as they seem.

As you have observed, the key quantity can be obtained by Taylor expansion and in the nutshell this is the action of symmetry of the system in every infinitesimal moment. So as all physicists or engineers will do, you do an approximation and discard all higher order terms. You can find that this first order approximation captures the key ingredient of this action at $ t = 0 $.
But if we want this action to describe a particular symmetry, what do we wish it to do? If you go back the to idea of symmetry, you will quickly find that, we don't need an extra parameter to describe the symmetry. In symmetry of a square, circle, straight line ... etc, we only refer the object to itself in a different way. There is no place for an extra parameter.
If this action $\sigma$ also describes some kind of symmetry, then this first variable $t$ shouldn't have any specific meaning either, or in the other word, at $ t = 0, t = e, t = 100^{100^{100}} $ or whatever value of $t$, $\sigma$ should still represent the same symmetry. What matters is then how much $t$ changes. For instance, if $t$ is discrete and $\sigma$ is just symmetry on an object like a regular hexagon, then $t$ simply describes how many times you apply the same action; if $t$ is continuous and $\sigma$ is rotation of sphere along an axis, $t$ describes how much angle you have rotated it.
For example, if particular value of $t$ does not matter, why not just assume that $ \sigma ( 0, x ) = x $ for all $ x \in B $? You can also assume $ \sigma ( 100^{100^{100}}, x ) = x $ for all $ x \in B $ if you wish so.
Next, if we want to apply this action to an element of $B$ for an amount of change in $t$, say $ x \in B $ and the difference is $dt$, what matters eventually should only be these two quantities, $x$ and $dt$, but there might be multiple pair of elements in $A,B$ such that $\sigma$ take the same value, say $ \sigma( 0, x ) = \sigma ( t_0, x_0 ) = x $. Then from our observation above, we should have $ \sigma ( dt, x ) = \sigma ( dt, \sigma ( t_0, x_0 ) ) = \sigma ( t_0 + dt, x_0 ) $, where the last equality follows from our observation that $t$ should be the parameter that measures how much you apply the symmetry.
Then the last ingredient is, how you apply a particular amount of symmetry should not matter as well. For instance, to apply $6$ times of the same symmetry on a regular hexagon, applying it one at a time and $6$ all together should give you the same answer. This leads to the semigroup property $$ \sigma( s, \sigma ( t, x ) ) = \sigma ( s + t, x ). $$

Let's pause for a second and make a remark. If you recall the theory of autonomous ODEs, you will find that this concept of action is very alike the solution of an autonomous ODE, and this is indeed true. Sometimes you can also reverse the time in the equation in an autonomous system, which makes sense for symmetry intuitively as well. In the case of autonomous ODE, the symmetry is in time so it does not matter when you start the system. Only the initial condition matters.

Let's now explore why we end up with the object infinitesimal generator. Let $t$ be a continuous parameter. What we want to know is, can we write down $\sigma$ as a formula of a simpler object in terms of $t$. Using the idea of the linear approximation, we imagine that if $dt$ is small enough, and we know what $ \sigma ( dt, x ) $ is for all $ x \in B $, then we can repeat this process to get the symmetry/action for any $t$.
Using the semigroup property of $\sigma$, we can deduce that, if $dt$ is of the form $1/n$ for some natural number $n$, then $ \sigma ( n \cdot dt, x ) = \sigma ( 1, x ) $. Let's write this action by $ L_n : B \to B $ with $ x \mapsto L_n x := \sigma( dt, x ) $. Now using $L_n$, we can find the action by $\sigma$ at any number of the form $ k / n $ for any natural number $k$, which is $ (L_n)^k x $. But you quickly run into the problem that the limit of $L_n$, whatever that means, as $ n \to \infty $, is the identity map, since $ \sigma( 0, x ) = x $ by definition.
This is best illustrated by an example. Let's consider $L_n$ as the translation action on smooth functions, namely $ ( L_n f ) (x) = f ( x + dt ) $. It is obvious that as $ n \to \infty $, $L_n$ is the identity operator since $$ \lim_{ dt \to 0^+ } f( x + dt ) = f(x). $$
However, we can approximate this action by linearization $ f( x + dt ) = f (x) + f'(x)dt $ and we know that by calculating $$ \frac{ f ( x + dt ) - f(x) }{dt} \approx f'(x) = L_n, $$
the action/operator in a very short amount of time is just the differential operator $D$ (or $\frac{d}{dx}, D_x$). If the function $f$ is smooth enough (analytic), then you can recover the action $\sigma$ by applying the operator $e^{dtD}$ to the function. This operator is well-defined on domain of $D$ throught the series $$ e^A := 1 + A + \frac{1}{2!} A^2 + \frac{1}{3!} A^3 + \ldots. $$ This is simply a consequence of the Taylor expansion: $$ e^{dtD} f(x) = \big( 1 + dtD + \frac{1}{2!} dt^2 D^2 + \ldots \big) f(x) = f(x) + dt f'(x) + \frac{1}{2!} dt^2 f''(x) + \ldots = f(x+dt). $$
In general, if $\sigma$ is just a random function from $ A \times B $ to $B$, then this derivative usually does not give you a useful picture of how this function behaves as a whole, but since $\sigma$ is a special function that satisfies the semigroup property, you can see that this derivative is independent on the value of $t$: $$ \sigma ( t + dt, x ) = \sigma ( dt, \sigma( t, x ) ), $$ or, more precisely, if $ y = \sigma(t,x) $ for some $ x \in B $, we have $$ \frac{ \sigma( t + dt, x ) - \sigma( t, x ) }{dt} = \frac{ \sigma( dt, \sigma( t, x ) ) - \sigma( t, x ) }{dt} = \frac{ \sigma( 
dt, y ) - y }{dt} = \frac{ \sigma( dt, y ) - \sigma( 0, y ) }{dt}. $$
Above obsevation leads to the definition of infinitesimal generator: for all $ x \in B $, we define
\begin{align} 
L(x) & := \lim_{ dt \to 0^+ } \frac{ \sigma( dt, x ) - \sigma( 0, x ) }{dt} \\
& \left( = \lim_{ dt \to 0^+ } \frac{ \sigma(dt, x) - x }{dt} \textrm{ if we assume } \sigma( 0, x ) = x \right),
\end{align}
or, you can leave out the argument $x$ and just write $$ L := \lim_{ dt \to 0^+ } \frac{ \sigma( dt, \cdot ) - \sigma( 0, \cdot ) }{dt}. $$ The terminology is evident from the observation too. It is a generator since it captures the whole action and can generate the whole action; it is infinitesimal since it tells you how it behaves if you change the parameter infinitesimally.

Hopefully this lines up with your intuition now and it makes sense to consider these two conditions. After you understand why we consider this object, the rest is just some math theory. You can see its interpretation in differential geometry and in PDE and stochastic analysis.
This topic has some surprising connection to other objects under certain conditions. For example, you can establish one to one correspondence between  a PDE, a family of semigroup, a stochastic process, a brownian motion, a Dirichlet form (energy form). See for instance Hille-Yoshida Theorem.
